# How can reduce height and download pdf using FPDF?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function to generate pdf using **Fpdf** in laravel. 
My problems are:

1. After all Cell I have some extra space. I need to remove that. Please find the image given below.
2. How can I download this pdf file in to my system. Currently it's just showing in to browser. Code samples are given below.

**Code**

Controller: Controller.php

```
public function index()
    {
        $orders = Order::select('firstname', 'lastname', 'street', 'postal', 'country')->get();
        foreach ($orders as $order){
            Fpdf::SetMargins(5, 5, 5);
            Fpdf::AddPage('L', array(60,90), 'A4');
            Fpdf::SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
            Fpdf::SetFont('helvetica', '', 7); //IF bold letter SetFont('Arial','B',14)
            Fpdf::SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
            Fpdf::Cell(10,5,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', 'Falls unzustellbar, zurück an Absender'),0,"1","L");
            Fpdf::SetFont('','U');
            Fpdf::Cell(10,5,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', 'schrillALARM.jetzt c/o 365group • Grasgasse 2 • 93047 Regensburg'),0,"1","L");
            Fpdf::SetFont('helvetica', '', 11);
            Fpdf::Cell(10,5,$order->firstname,0,1,"L");
            Fpdf::Cell(10,5,$order->lastname,0,1,"L");
            Fpdf::Cell(10,5,$order->street,0,1,"L");
            Fpdf::Cell(10,5,$order->postal,0,1,"L");
            Fpdf::Cell(10,5,$order->country,0,1,"L");
        }
        Fpdf::Output();
        exit;
    }
```

Route: Route::get('/test', 'Controller@index');

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No experience with FDPF, but you can download this way:

```
Route::get(
    'download/pdf/{pdf}',
    function ($pdf) {
        $file = // Get file
        return response()->download($file);
    }
);
```

Or just from your controller with

```
return response()->download($pdf);
```

Answer (score 0):

for saving, just specify output path and filename in your output call string

```
Fpdf::Output([string dest [, string name [, boolean isUTF8]]])
```

For your white space though, when you're constructing your PDF document, you can use a default size of one of the following: A3, A4, A5, Letter, Legal with A4 being default. However, you can also declare custom sizes. This is more than likely what you're looking for, as you'll want to play with the sizes to get it with the amount of white space you're looking for. FPDF puts out the canvas first then fills it, so you're white space is coming from a canvas that is too big. This can be done in the constructor, or AddPage as you have done.

VIA Constructor:

```
//(L)andscape or (P)ortrait, unit type (mm millimeters), array size in mm
$pdf = new FPDF('L','mm',array(100,150));
```

VIA AddPage (must likely what you're looking for):
currently you have:

```
Fpdf::AddPage('L', array(60,90), 'A4');
```

however, params are supposed to be landscape/portrait, Predefined or custom size array, then rotation. So try this:

```
Fpdf::AddPage('L', array(60,90));
```

Now you'll need to play with those numbers, more than likely the 90, and shorten that up to rid yourself of the white space.